# Configure a second computer for iOS app distribution

Tags: xcode, certificate, provisioning

I've followed the guidelines and configured fine my desktop for Ad-Hoc distribution (requested certificate from the CA, created the main Certificate with my name, created a provisioning associated to devices, and so on).

Now I have my laptop and I need to configure it with the same account (not creating a team development account, but an admin one). I didn't recreate the certificate from the CA because I already have my valid certificate online (the one associated with the provisioning), and I downloaded it and installed it in my keychain. But if I open Xcode and look for a valid provisioning, it says "profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain".
Do I need to recreate my own certificate every time I switch from my workstation to the one in my office?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a CA it uses a private key on your system. You need to copy that to your laptop in order for XCode to use the CA.

http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action (need to be logged in)

Here is a helpful article on the topic:

http://www.buggyprogrammer.co.uk/2010/12/13/sharing-ios-distribution-certificate/

I'm in the process of doing this myself, so I'm not sure if this works, but seems like it should.